# cakephp:$this->Auth->user() login not working on production server?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, components, production-environment

I'm having a problem with the Auth component on the production server. When I enter the username and password and click on login, nothing happens except the password text box clears itself. I'm getting 'I'm in loginFailure'. I have no idea on why it is not going into 'if ($this->Auth->user())' at all.

Earlier on my development server this Auth component was working perfectly fine. I was able to login a user and once the user logins in, the report card pdf file for his/her child will be displayed.

Can anyone point out on what mistake i'm making? Thank you.

merry_parents_controller.php

```
class MerryParentsController extends AppController{

var $name='MerryParents';
function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect=false;
                        //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
}

function login(){
    echo "i'm in login";
    if ($this->Auth->user()){
        debug($this->Auth->user());
        $this->data=$this->Auth->user();
        if (!empty($this->data)){

                    $student_info=$this->MerryParent->Student->getStudents($this->data['MerryParent']['id']);
                    $this->set('student_info',$student_info);
                    print_r($student_info); 
                    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'aptitudes','action'=>'viewpdf',$student_info['Student']['id']));
                    //$this->render('/aptitudes/viewpdf');  
            }
        else{
            echo 'Auth user has not been set';
            }

    }
    else
        echo "Failure";

}
}
```

login.ctp

```
<?php
//var_dump($this->data);
$this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Form->create('MerryParent',array('action'=>'login'));
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.username',array('label'=>'Name'));
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.password', array('value'=>''));
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

app_controller.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
var $components=array('Auth','Session','Cookie','Email','Security','RequestHandler','Cookie');
var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Ajax','Javascript','Session');

function beforeFilter(){
  if (isset($this->Auth)){
        $this->Auth->userModel='MerryParent';
        $this->Auth->loginAction=array('controller'=>'merry_parents','action'=>'login');
                    /*var_dump($this->data);
                    debug($this->Auth->user);*/
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect=array('controller'=>'aptitudes','action'=>'viewpdf');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect=array('controller'=>'merry_parents','action'=>'register');
        $this->Auth->authorize='controller';
      }
   else
        $this->Session->setFlash('Auth has not been set');  

}

function isAuthorized(){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Something is really wrong with your `login` function. You are clearing the data that is being passed to this function by doing $this->data = $this->Auth->user(). This will only work if you are already logged in. You should log in first by passing this->data to the Auth Login Function...

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php
//var_dump($this->data);
$this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Form->create('MerryParent',array('action'=>'login'));
echo $this->Form->input('username',array('label'=>'Name'));
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('value'=>''));
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

try this login function:

```
function login(){
    echo "i'm in login";
    if (!empty($this->data)){
        if($this->Auth->login($this->data)) {
            debug($this->Auth->user());
            $this->data=$this->Auth->user();
            if (!empty($this->data)){
                $student_info=$this->MerryParent->Student->getStudents($this->data['MerryParent']['id']);
                $this->set('student_info',$student_info);
                print_r($student_info); 
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'aptitudes','action'=>'viewpdf',$student_info['Student']['id']));
                //$this->render('/aptitudes/viewpdf');  
            } else {
                echo 'Auth user has not been set';
            }
        }
    } else echo "Failure";
}
```

Comment: I tried ur solution and the result is the same as above. Nothing happens.

Comment: yes it works now. But there were 2 problems: 1) the code in login function. 2)Security.salt & Security.cipherSeed in core.php.

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 problems. After I modified login function as per CodeParadox's answer, It still wasn't working till I modified core.php's Security.salt and Security.cipherSeed. I just copied the values for salt and cipherSeed from my development server's core.php and it worked! :)

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra space in controller last line or other use php file like as "config","components" and "helpers"

<?php ?><Remove space>

Answer (score 0):

your Author.authorize Controller should be a capital letter case like below:

```
$this->Auth->authorize='Controller';
```